# objectaid uml explorer throwing exception

Tags: eclipse-plugin, objectaid

I have installed ObjectAid UML explorer in Eclipse Juno 4.2.2. Throws the following error when I launch it.
The selected wizard could not be started.
Plug-in com.objectaid.uml.cls was unable to load class com.objectaid.uml.cls.editor.NewClassDiagramWizard.
JVMCFRE003 bad major version; 
Appreciate your insights and help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

'Bad major version' means the code was compiled for a newer version of Java that the one you are using.

According to the ObjectAid [download page](http://www.objectaid.com/download) the current 1.2.x releases require Java 8.

Use the older 1.1.x release if you are using Java 6 or 7.